# Is there a "database level" method of stopping EF 4.2 adding spaces to autogenerated table and column names?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, conventions, ef4-code-only, fluent-interface

I'm using Entity Framework 4.2 in code-only "mode". I'm letting it autogenerate my database from the model.

However, it's adding spaces to my table and column names based on title-casing - e.g. a `CustomerOrder` class is mapped to a `[Customer Orders]` table and a `ProductNumber` property is mapped to a `[Product Number]` field.

Is there any way of preventing this from happening - short of configuring every table and property name via the Fluent API (which I know how to do)?

Is this a new 4.2 thing?

Comment: Hi... I could not reproduce this behavior with EF 4.2 CTP, that is the one I have here. Could you tell more about how to do this happen?

Comment: Actually, I think it might be a third party library causing a side effect. I'm looking into this just now. It's an inherited application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `OnModelCreating` of your `DataContext` and change the conventions used by entity framework... there may be a convention of adding spaces before upper-case letters. Remove the convention and you are done.

The conventions are inside the `modelBuilder` object passed as argument to that method.
It has a `Conventions` property that you can inspect, and see if the convention exists there.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I had a look at the conventions list, but couldn't see an obvious one. Do you know which one it is? I've not noticed this before, so wondering if it's new.

Comment: I looked at Reflector to see all the convention types in the EntityFramework 4.2, but I found no one suggesting that it adds spaces, the only one convention about naming I found was `PluralizingTableNameConvention`. I am trying to reproduce this here... to see if the spaces thing show up here.